# Pandas Round to Nearest first of Month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of dates that are around the 30th - 2nd and I'd like to round all of these to the first of that month (roundup for the 30th/31st and down for 1st/2nd and so on).

How would I do this within my pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your 'date' column data type is a date type. For example,

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

will change the dtype of the 'date' column to datetime64[ns].

Next consider the scope of the problem. Do you want to have Feb 28th/29th changed? I'll assume you only want to change the dates you have specified. This can be done easily in two parts. First find the earlier dates and then move them forward, and then second find the later dates and move them back.

To move the early dates forward create a mask which selects the offending rows.

```
mask1 = (df['birth_date'].dt.day >= 30)
```

Then alter the dates with pandas .apply() method and a specifically tailored function. This should be vectorized and and thus reasonably fast.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
df.loc[mask1, 'birth_date'] = df.loc[mask1, 'birth_date'].apply(lambda date_in: (date_in + relativedelta(months=+1)).replace(day=1))
```

Similarly for the dates which need to be moved earlier (which is just when day = 2) we have as follows.

```
mask2 = (df['birth_date'].dt.day == 2)
df.loc[mask2, 'birth_date'] = df.loc[mask2, 'birth_date'].apply(lambda date_in: (date_in).replace(day=1))
```

For example:

Input:

```
raw_data = {'name': ['Willard Morris', 'Al Jennings', 'Omar Mullins', 'Spencer McDaniel'],
'age': [20, 19, 22, 21],
'favorite_color': ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', "green"],
'grade': [88, 92, 95, 70],
'birth_date': ['01-02-1996', '08-05-1997', '04-30-1996', '12-16-1995']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, index = ['Willard Morris', 'Al Jennings', 'Omar Mullins', 'Spencer McDaniel'])
df['birth_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birth_date'])
df
```

Output:

```
name                age    favorite_color    grade    birth_date('%y%m%d')

Willard Morris      20     blue              88       1996-01-02
Al Jennings         19     red               92       1997-08-05
Omar Mullins        22     yellow            95       1996-04-30
Spencer McDaniel    21     green             70       1995-12-16
```

Input:

```
mask1 = (df['birth_date'].dt.day >= 30)
mask2 = (df['birth_date'].dt.day == 2)
df.loc[mask1, 'birth_date'] = df.loc[mask1, 'birth_date'].apply(lambda date_in: (date_in + relativedelta(months=+1)).replace(day=1))
df.loc[mask2, 'birth_date'] = df.loc[mask2, 'birth_date'].apply(lambda date_in: date_in.replace(day=1))
df
```

Output:

```
name                age    favorite_color    grade    birth_date('%y%m%d')

Willard Morris      20     blue              88       1996-01-01
Al Jennings         19     red               92       1997-08-05
Omar Mullins        22     yellow            95       1996-05-01
Spencer McDaniel    21     green             70       1995-12-16
```

Comment: Slight typo! It's df.loc[mask*2*, 'birth_date'] = df.loc[mask2, 'birth_date'].apply(lambda date_in: (date_in).replace(day=1)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is round up and down the days closest to the beginning of the month, you can do it in two steps:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/25/2018 11:59:00', periods=14, freq='D')
s = pd.Series(rng)

# round down 
s.where(((s.dt.day == 1) | (s.dt.day > 2)), 
        lambda x: x + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1), inplace=True)

# round up 
s.where(s.dt.day < 30, lambda x: x + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0), inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
In [317]: s
Out[317]: 
0    2018-01-25 11:59:00
1    2018-01-26 11:59:00
2    2018-01-27 11:59:00
3    2018-01-28 11:59:00
4    2018-01-29 11:59:00
5    2018-02-01 11:59:00
6    2018-02-01 11:59:00
7    2018-02-01 11:59:00
8    2018-02-01 11:59:00
9    2018-02-03 11:59:00
10   2018-02-04 11:59:00
11   2018-02-05 11:59:00
12   2018-02-06 11:59:00
13   2018-02-07 11:59:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```